# Why does the 1px <hr> appearance change?

Tags: css

I am at my wits end on this one. In Chrome, the ruler thickness changes depending on how many lines of text are underneath. In Firefox and IE it always remains 1px. Image below and here a fiddle (visit with Chrome to see the problem)
https://jsfiddle.net/Lh4qg7zc/

```
<div class="project-card">
    <div class="project-caption">
        <div class="pc-name">beloved homes</div>
        <hr class="project-caption-ruler">
        <div class="pc-type">Book</div>
        <div class="pc-task">International editing, verbal identity, copy adaptation</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="project-card">    
    <div class="project-caption">
        <div class="pc-name">beloved homes</div>
        <hr class="project-caption-ruler">
        <div class="pc-type">Book</div>
        <div class="pc-task">International editing, verbal identity, copy adaptation ... and an extra line...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.project-card {
    position: relative;
    background-color:brown;
    text-align: center;
    width: 380px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.project-caption {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 90%;
}

.pc-name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.project-caption-ruler {
    width: 166px;
    border:0;
    border-top:1px solid white;
}

.pc-type,
.pc-task {
    font-style: italic;
}

.pc-task {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the chrome developer tool (I think press F12) show any actual attribute changes to the element?

Comment: not that I can see, "Computed CSS" is the same for both instances

Answer (score 0):

I believe it has something to do with the fixed height of the parent containers. I've got a fix:

```css
.project-card {
    position: relative;
    background-color:brown;
    text-align: center;
    width: 380px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.project-caption {
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 90%;
}

.pc-name {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.project-caption-ruler {
    width: 166px;
    border: none;
    border-top:1px solid white;
}

.pc-type,
.pc-task {
    font-style: italic;
}

.pc-task {
    margin-top: 3px;
  line-height: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="project-card">
<div class="project-caption">
        <div class="pc-name">beloved homes</div>
        <hr class="project-caption-ruler">
        <div class="pc-type">Book</div>
        <div class="pc-task">International editing, verbal identity, copy adaptation</div>
    </div></div>
    
<div class="project-card">    
    <div class="project-caption">
        <div class="pc-name">beloved homes</div>
        <hr class="project-caption-ruler">
        <div class="pc-type">Book</div>
        <div class="pc-task">International editing, verbal identity, copy adaptation ... and an extra line...</div>
    </div></div>
```

I've simply added a `line-height: 16px;` to your `.pc-task` class.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh4qg7zc/3/

EDIT - It is indeed something to do with the fixed height you've put on the parents, as I've removed in the following example fiddle and used padding instead: https://jsfiddle.net/Lh4qg7zc/4/

As you can see, the `hr`'s display the same.

Comment: Interesting. On jsfiddle it fixes the issue, but in my local dev it makes both lines thick instead. :-) Height seems involved. Disabling the `transform: translate` on the fiddle makes both lines smooth and thin as well.

Comment: @pastic Very interesting. There's always more than 1 way of resolving things!

Comment: @wilkinson regrettably I need those width and height values. Though, I find that if I do your `line-height` trick together with `height:1px` on the `hr` it seems to be working as well. How did you think of putting line-height on the `.pc-task` class? I would never have thought of that since the problem was with the `hr`.

Comment: @pastic It can just be a case of trial and error... Try this, try that, if that doesn't work, try this other thing. Basically how I learned to code!!